# Why does a XORed image returns such a strange thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Okay so I'm making a program using sockets to do efficient screen sharing.
The client (who will send the images) sends, first, an original image that will be the source for the previous images, after that it sends the XOR of the previous image with the current one, to reduce the sent data.

The server then receives them and stores them in a variable called self.source_image, and XORs them back to the original image.

A fully functional code, which I based myself on, is this

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import mss
import time

sct = mss.mss()
rect = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}
count = 10

last_image = None
final_image = None

for i in range(count):
    img = sct.grab(rect)
    img_array = np.flip(np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)[:, :, :3], 2)

    if last_image is None:
        last_image = img_array
    else:
        xor_image = img_array ^ last_image
        final_image = last_image ^ xor_image # server-side
        last_image = final_image

    time.sleep(1)

img_pillow = Image.fromarray(final_image).convert('RGB')
img_pillow = img_pillow.resize((1280, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)

img_pillow.show()
```

This code works fine and is very fast, so I decided to implement it on a socket-client-server system.

At the client:

```py
from PIL import Image
import mss
import numpy as np

def grab_screen():
        rect = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}
        last_image = None

        with mss.mss() as sct:
            while True:
                img = sct.grab(rect)
                img_array = np.flip(np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)[:, :, :3], 2)

                if last_image is None:
                    last_image = img_array
                    send_image_to_server(img_array)
                else:
                    xor_image = img_array ^ last_image
                    last_image = img_array
                    send_image_to_server(xor_image)
```

At the server

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class Server:
  def __init__(self):
      self.source_image = None
      
  def convert_np_to_pillow(self, np_array):
    img_pillow = Image.fromarray(np_array).convert('RGB')
    img_pillow = img_pillow.resize((1280, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_pillow.show()

  def update_image(self, pixels):
        # Method for loading images using numpy XOR.
        # At the first image, pixels is a complete image
        # containing all the pixels. The following would just
        # have the XORed image.
        
        if self.source_image is None:
            self.source_image = pixels
            self.convert_np_to_pillow(pixels)

        else:
            xor_image = self.source_image ^ pixels
            self.source_image = xor_image

            self.convert_np_to_pillow(xor_image)
```

But the result is quite different. Why's that happening?

[image: Different result]

Comment: Please share the input images too. Did you try it all locally without any socket stuff?